# Remove all span elements by classname?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a classname called `notag`. When i click a button, it triggers my onclick event to call my function. Within the function i want it to remove / delete all span elements that has that classname `notag`.

My attempts are below but no luck! Please help thanks.

```
onclick="replaceQueuePlaylist()"

function replaceQueuePlaylist()
{
    $("span").attr('notag').remove(); //dont work
    $('.notag').remove(); //also dont work
}
```

Comment: `$('.notag').remove();` should work, Can you share HTML?

Comment: Thats what i thought but doesnt? :/

Comment: So you have another bug somewhere.

Comment: Is that any error showing in  your console

Comment: You could also use .detach()

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki after reading your message you got me thinking and you were right! I did have a small bug which is now patched up and working. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> $("span").attr('notag').remove(); //dont work

**This won't work because your elements have a class named `notag`, and not an attribute. `class` itself is an attribute with value `notag` in `<div class='notag'> hello world </div>`**

There's no need to explicitly use `.each()` as using `$(selector).remove()` will automatically iterate through each element with the selection criteria and remove it.

```js
$('#delete-em').on('click', function(){
    $('.delete-me').remove();  
});
```

```css
.delete-me{
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    margin: 5px;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='delete-me'></div>
<div class='delete-me'></div>
<div class='delete-me'></div>
<div class='delete-me'></div>

<button id="delete-em">Remove</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

With [jQuery.remove()](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) you can directly remove all the set of matched elements from the DOM:

```
function replaceQueuePlaylist() {
    $('span.notag').remove();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one;

```
 function replaceQueuePlaylist() {
    $("span.notag").each(function () {
        $(this).remove();
    });
 }
```

Finds all the spans with notag class name and delete them.

Answer (score 0):

Just add these lines in your function. Happy coding

```
$("span.notag").each(function () {
    $(this).remove();
});
```